# Convert Date to Fiscal Period with C#

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Is there a standard or convenient way to get the current financial period in a custom workflow activity and use it to convert a calendar date field to it's financial date?

Fiscal periods are monthly.
Manually removing months from the date field to get the fiscal date is not really an option.

I have found this set, but it is empty:

```html
XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/MonthlyFiscalCalendarSet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this

```html
<d:FiscalCalendarStart m:type="Edm.DateTime">
    2013-10-01T10:59:00Z
</d:FiscalCalendarStart>
```

in

```
/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/OrganizationSet
```

This method returns the fiscal period (as month) from a calendar date:

```c#
/* returns month, year */
private Tuple<int, int> GetFinancialDate(WorkflowContext context, DateTime? date)
{
    var start = context.Linq.OrganizationSet
        .FirstOrDefault().FiscalCalendarStart;
    if (date.HasValue && start.HasValue)
    {
        var localDate = date.Value.ToLocalTime();
        var month = localDate.Month - start.Value.ToLocalTime().Month + 1; // +1 because not 0 based
        var year = (localDate.Month == 1) ? localDate.Year : localDate.Year + 1; // if it is Jan then do not move the year forward - move forward for Feb onward
        if (month <= 0) // the date is in the previous financial year, 0 would be the last period of the previous fiscal year
        {
            --year; // move to the previous year
            month = month + 12; // month is negative or 0 before this, so is 12 or less after
        }
        return Tuple.Create(month, year);
    }
    return Tuple.Create(0, 0);
}
```